# Python - numpy: How to divide items in row between themselves

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have matrix:

```
[[a b c]
[d e f]
[g h i]]
```

in this matrix I want to do this:

```
b/a * c/b = result
e/d * f/e = result
h/g * i/h = result
```

Is there soution for divide and multiply items with using numpy?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you have written. `b/a * c/b` is the same as `a * c`, right? In general you can get the `n` th column of an array `x` with `x[:, n]` and you can multiply and divide them elementwise as `x * y` and `x / y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `b`s cancel in

```
b/a * c/b
```

so the result would be `c/a`. There is a similar cancelation on each row.

So the result is the third column divided by the first column:

```
result = arr[:,2] / arr[:,0]
```